# no icon on my desktop ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, icons

after an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, i have no icon on my desktop.
I've tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

but i have now an error:
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrompu : secondary link is the same as principal one /usr/bin/mpicc

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean no icons or a certain icon the question is not clear.

Comment: And do you now have icons? Question is unclear. Clarify. Also carefully reproduce the entire error message, and format it as code.

Comment: sudo apt upgrade ends with an error: